# ¿Cómo salir de una función sin devolver nada?

Tags: java, condiciones, while

Estoy intentado hacer un método que al pulsar cero, salga del método y no me retorne nada. Pero no logro hacerlo, aunque rompa y salga con el break siempre me devuelve el cero como valor.

```
/**
 * Método para introducir el id y comprobar que es correcto
 * @return - El id del vino como entero
 */
private static int introducirIdVino(){
    int idVino = 0;
    while (idVino <= 0 || idVino > 99999) {            
        idVino = Utilidades.leerEntero("\nIntroduce el Id del vino, debe estar entre 1 y 99999");
        if (idVino == 0){
            break;
        }
        if (existeVino(idVino)) {
            Utilidades.visualizarMensaje("Ese vino ya existe, introduzca un nuevo ID por favor");
            idVino = 0;
        } 
    }
    return idVino;
}
```

Comment: Siempre te va devolver cero porque le asignas al inicio de la función. No sé si en Java puedas asignar un tipo int? como en Swift para que asignes null a un integer.

Comment: En la declaración del método le dices que devuelva un entero, "private static int nombreDelMétodo(), pues entonces siempre te va a devolver un entero, pues así se lo estás especificando,

Comment: Lo he solucionado en el main, justo después de llamar al método y lo evaluo, si me devuelve ese 0, salgo sin problemas

        int idVino = introducirIdVino();
        if (idVino == 0) {
            return;
        }

Comment: El metodo devuelve un int(tipo primitivo) o sea que siempre que retornes vas a devolver un valor. Si quieres devolver por ejemplo null tiene que ser Integer. para tipos primitivos podrias tener un valor que signifique que no devuelves nada. Por ejemplo: -1
Y en cualquier caso tendras que revisar el valor devuelto en el codigo que espera el valor.

Comment: A que te refieres con **salga del método y no me retorne nada**? necesitas una funcion void?, por otro lado cortas tu while siempre que `idVino==0` y retornas `idVino`, razon por la cual dicha funcion siempre te retornara 0.

Comment: La única forma de no devolver nada es con `void` o lanzando una excepción.

Answer (score 0):

el detalle como bien lo comentan es que inicializas el 0 y no deberías de hacerlo, solo en caso de que no exista.

Prueba con el siguiente codigo.

```
/**
 * Método para introducir el id y comprobar que es correcto
 * @return - El id del vino como entero
 */
private static int introducirIdVino(){
    int idVino = 0;
    while (idVino == 0) {            
        idVino = Utilidades.leerEntero("\nIntroduce el Id del vino, debe estar entre 1 y 99999");

        if (existeVino(idVino)) {
            Utilidades.visualizarMensaje("Ese vino ya existe, introduzca un nuevo ID por favor");
            idVino = 0;
        } 
    }
    return idVino;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que necesitas, pero primero ejecuta este programa tal cual está así lo comprendes, luego lo adaptas a tu programa.

Crea un nuevo proyecto y luego borras todo menos la linea `package nombreDeTuPaquete;`. Luego pega todo este código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuscaVinos {

    private static Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(introducirIdVino());
    }

    private static Integer introducirIdVino(){

        Integer idVino = 0;//Integer: clase wrap de int, necesaria para retornar null
        boolean yaExiste;

        do {            
            yaExiste =false;
            System.out.println("Introduce el Id del vino, debe estar entre 1 y 99999");
            idVino =scanner.nextInt();

            if (idVino == 0)
                return null;
            //como yo no tengo el método existeVino(int idVino) lo voy a simular con esto:
            else if(idVino == 1 || idVino == 2 || idVino == 3)
            {
                yaExiste =true;
                System.out.println("Ese vino ya existe");
            }
        }
        while (idVino <= 0 || idVino > 99999 || yaExiste);

        return idVino;
    }
}
```

Como te decían en los comentarios, si declaras un método que retorna algo, no es posible que no retorne nada. Lo que se hace es decirle que retorne `null`.
El `do while` es similar al `while` solo que aquel se usa para cuando se necesita 
que entre por primera vez. Fijate que el programa queda allí atrapado (dentro del bucle) mientras `idVino` es inválido o ya existe, y solo va a salir de allí cuando ya no se cumpla la condición, retornando `idVino`, o bien cuando se ingresa `0`, en ese caso retornando **null**. Tené en cuenta que el `return` también es como un `break`, en el sentido que corta, no sigue ejecutando las lineas de código que siguen.

Answer (score -1):

cambia el break por **return null**

Comment: Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: la clase int no te va a dejar usar este codigo, ya que no es nullable...

Comment: **null** no funciona con tipos primitivos. Sí, con los envolventes